# Unit testing routes with Mock ActivatedRoute configuration

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am configuring test spec for my component which has routes, also I have defined my spec with dependencies as follows. And the ActivatedRoute has these properties, But I don't see its object/instance being created while debugging my test spec. Also I have referred different methods of mocking ActivatedRoute but nothing is helping me. Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong

```js
class UserInfotypeDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor(
        private userInfotypeDetailService: UserInfotypeDetailService,
        private appLookupService: AppLookupService,
        private router: Router,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ) {}

 performAction(event: { action: string; objectKey: string | null }) {
    let extras: any = { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute };
    if (event.objectKey) {
          extras.queryParams = { objectKey: event.objectKey };
    }

    switch (event.action) {
      case "new":
      case "edit":
      case "copy":
      case "view":
        this.router.navigate([event.action], extras);
        break;
      case "delete":
        this.deleteRecord(event.objectKey as string);
    }
  }

}
```

Here is my Routes:

```js
{
        path: "infotype/:id",
        component: UserInfotypeDetailComponent,
        outlet: "slidein",
        children: [
          {
            path: "new",
            component: UserRecordFormComponent,
            data: { actionId: "A", buttonDesc: "Save" }
          },
          {
            path: "edit",
            component: UserRecordFormComponent,
            data: { actionId: "E", buttonDesc: "Update" }
          },
          {
            path: "copy",
            component: UserRecordFormComponent,
            data: { actionId: "C", buttonDesc: "Save" }
          },
          {
            path: "view",
            component: UserRecordFormComponent,
            data: { actionId: "V", actionDesc: "View" }
          }
        ]
      }
```

And my test spec is as follows:

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
              RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
                BrowserAnimationsModule,
                RouterModule
            ],
            declarations: [
                UserInfotypeDetailComponent
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {
                                          outlet: "slidein",
                                          params: of({ 
                                              id: "0009"
                                          })
                                      }
                },
                { provide: AppLookupService, useClass: AppLookupServiceStub },
                { provide: UserInfotypeDetailService, useClass: UserInfotypeDetailServiceStub },
                { provide: Router, useClass: AppRouterStub }
            ],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    class AppRouterStub {
        navigate() {}
    }
```

And test case:

```js
it('make expect calls to router navigate', fakeAsync(() => {
      let router = TestBed.get(Router);
      let spy = spyOn(router, 'navigate');

      component.performAction(event);

      let extras: any = { relativeTo: ActivatedRoute };
      if (event.objectKey) {
        extras.queryParams = { objectKey: event.objectKey };
      }
      fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith([event.action], extras);
    }))
```

The error that it throws is:

> "spy navigate to have been called with [ [ 'edit' ], Object({ relativeTo: Function, queryParams: Object({ objectKey: '36353539363A393C3535353E352525252525253E3E3E3E363738363735363E35363536353535' }) }) ] but actual calls were [ [ 'edit' ], Object({ relativeTo: Object({ snapshot: Object({  }), parent: Object({ params: Subject({ _isScalar: false, observers: [  ], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, thrownError: null }) }), params: Subject({ _isScalar: false, observers: [  ], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, thrownError: null }), queryParams: Subject({ _isScalar: false, observers: [  ], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, thrownError: null }), testParams: Object({ id: '0009' }) }), queryParams: Object({ objectKey: '36353539363A393C3535353E352525252525253E3E3E3E363738363735363E35363536353535' }) }) ]."

Answer (score 1):

It's failing because with

```
let extras: any = { relativeTo: ActivatedRoute };
```

you are actually using angular's `ActivatedRoute` but what you should be using is the `useValue` which you have defined in `providers`.

**Make activatedRoute `public` in `constructor` of the component, so that we can access it**

```
public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
public router : Router
```

Try:

```
it('make expect calls to router navigate', fakeAsync(() => {
      spyOn(component.router, 'navigate');

      component.performAction(event);
      // I hope you have defined "event" somewhere in code, because I can't see
      // it anywhere here !

      let extras: any = { relativeTo: component.activatedRoute};
      if (event.objectKey) {
        extras.queryParams = { objectKey: event.objectKey };
      }

      expect(component.router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith([event.action], extras);
    }))
```

Comment: I did try the above suggestion, it still returns the same error.

Comment: @SoujanyaJ can u share the new code as per my suggestion and error screenshot ? The error says `Object({ snapshot: Object({ })` etc etc which should not come if you have used  `component.activatedRoute` as per my suggestion. Let me know once u provide both in your question